# Ubuntu 16.04 not detecting SATA drives on Integrated SAS Controller

Tags: 16.04, sata, scsi

**Problem Statement :** I have connected 4 SATA drives to an internal SAS connector on my motherboard. They appear fine in the BIOS but Ubuntu doesn't seem to be able to detect them. I don't get anything on fdisk or lsblk. I would like to be able to use these SATA drives through SAS connectors because the motherboard doesn't have enough SATA-only connectors.

**Hardware :** I have a Fujitsu D3118-A22 GS1 motherboard that has 2 SAS/SATA connectors. The chipset is Intel C602. The drives are Seagate Barracuda 2TB SATA drives.

**Research :** (Disclaimer : I have almost no idea about how linux kernel is built/works. I just followed bread crumbs). The only indication I get about SATA over SAS is from `lspci -knn | grep SCSI` that returns

```
05:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller [0107]: Intel Corporation C602 chipset 4-Port SATA Storage Control Unit [8086:1d6b] (rev 05)
```

I further looked up the device code and found that I **probably** need Intel(R) C600 Series Chipset SAS Controller (https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SCSI_ISCI.html), which is available through `isci` module. The line

```
lkddb pci 8086 1d6b .... .... ...... : CONFIG_SCSI CONFIG_SCSI_ISCI : drivers/scsi/isci/init.c # in 3.17–3.19, 4.0–4.18
```

especially looked interesting. But I don't know how to use this information.
Then I looked up in the kernel config and it's marked to be included as a module.
[screenshot from 'make menuconfig' in '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-65-generic/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPWOv.png)

Can anyone tell me if including `isci` module will make my SATA drives visible? Second how to include it?

Another thing I found, but not sure if it's relevant is drivers for Intel RAID Controllers (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/2092/Intel-RAID-Controllers). Secondly, I don't know the model of integrated RAID/SAS controller on the motherboard.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find was to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04. That solved the problem like a breeze.